# Text from fragment is showing up inside my navbar

Tags: java, android

i have been trying to fix this error but cant get it to work.
[Here you find a picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbcvF.png) the problem is that my text of the fragment is showing up in the navbar. i hope somebody can help me out with this!

activity_main code xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigationView">
    >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sander's app"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.036" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.998"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="121dp" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActiviy java code:

```
package com.example.myapp;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;



import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private Button button;

    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "com.example.myapp.EXTRA_TEXT";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
//        final View v = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
//        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Welkom terug gebruiker!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
//        snackbar.setAnchorView(fab);
//        snackbar.show();


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.firstFragment);






    }
    FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
    SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
    ThirdFragment thirdFragment = new ThirdFragment();

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, firstFragment).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.games:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, secondFragment).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.maps:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, thirdFragment).commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;

    }























    public void openSecondActivity() {
        EditText editTextTextPersonName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        String text = editTextTextPersonName.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, text);

        startActivity(intent);

    }



    }
```

fragment_second xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second activity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SecondFragment java

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link SecondFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public SecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SecondFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static SecondFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        View v = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
//        Snackbar.make(v, "U bent nu in games.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }
}
```

bottom_menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/games"
        android:title="Games"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_games"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/maps"
        android:title="Maps"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map" />
</menu>
```

my_nav xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.ThirdFragment"
        android:label="fragment_third"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_third" />
</navigation>
```

I hope somebody can help because i have been trying for hours

Comment: `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX/Y` won't be applied at runtime.. they are only for design purpose.

Comment: In my fragment that i want to show (fragment_second.xml) i dont use the "tools:layoute_editor_absoluteX/Y" i also deleted it now but it doesnt have any effect.